# How to create a deployment pipeline with React and Flask on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, flask, heroku

I am building a small app using Python/Flask for the backend and React for the main part of the frontend. However, I have some auxiliary pages that are just HTML/CSS that I have in a `/templates` folder in my Flask app.

Whenever I make a change in my React app, I have to do a `npm run build` and then copy-paste the resulting `/build` directory into my Flask app, and then create a Blueprint for the React page (using this `/build` directory as the templates/static folder). Once I've copy/pasted this, I can commit to Github and deploy on Heroku.

This seems very hacky and I assume there's a more effective/efficient way to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything that fits my specific use case. Does anyone know if there's a better way to do this process?

Here is my directory structure:

```
wsgi.py (Flask entry point)
Procfile
requirements.txt
website
--- frontend-app (submodule React app repo)
--- build (compiled version of the React app using npm run build
--- other directories
--- __init__.py
```

Comment: You can use multiple buildpacks: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app. First, you need to build NodeJS (package.json must be in the root), then python

Comment: Please check my recent answer to a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65454190/7833514.

Comment: Karl, thanks so much for the response. I am trying to implement your solution but I have a slightly different repository structure: I have my Flask app as the main directory, and I copy the `/build` app into the Flask's `website` directory.

I have created a `package.json` in my base Flask directory with a `scripts` object inside of it, which says:

`"build": "cd website/frontend-app && npm install react-scripts && npm install && npm run build && rm -rf ../build && mv build ../build``"`

However, when I deploy on Heroku now, it just hangs during the deployment (no errors, but no deploy).