# Running npm run build in Heroku to serve a flask backend react frontend app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm

I've got a Flask app that also serves a React frontend by serving files from a `/build` folder that gets generated when I run `npm run build`.

My directory structure:

```
.
|-client/
|  |build/
|    |static/
|
|-server/
|  |main.py
```

In order to deploy my app to Heroku, I have to...

1. cd into client
2. run npm run build in order to generate the new static build of the react app
3. commit the changes to git

This works, but it's definitely a pain. It creates HUGE diffs in Github when we create PRs.

I'm wondering, is it possible to run `npm run build` in the Heroku pipeline? I think the Procfile is the way to go. I've tried a couple of things like adding

```
npm: cd client && npm run build
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn wsgi:app
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is more a Heroku question than a Flask question.

Yes, it's possible to run `npm run build` as part of your deployment.

Make sure that your app uses the Node.js buildpack along with the Python buildpack. Then create a `package.json` in your project root (sibling to server/ and client/). In that, add (other content of `package.json` omitted):

```
{
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "client/node_modules"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  }
}
```

Heroku will automatically pick up that build script and run the specified command(s). It'll also cache the node_modules in the client/ directory. The documentation around this is a bit sparse, but you can find the relevant info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#custom-caching).

You'll also want to remove and ignore the JS build directories from Git, as they're not needed any more. Just make sure the directory(/ies) used for storing the JS build artifacts exist at the time when Heroku runs the postbuild script.

I wrote a more in-depth guide about this on [here](https://www.karlsutt.com/articles/how-to-build-and-serve-spa-with-heroku-app/).

Comment: Yes! This is the correct answer, I did exactly what you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much for the help! I've been trying to achieve this for days.